# get result of function as displayed in DOM with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Look at this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/iOqhKPMKbwkeYIhf2m2j?p=preview

Is there any way to get the results values from getSum() as displayed in the DOM with angular for use in another function? Do i need to use jquery?

Edit: New plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `getSum()` in your `displaySum` function:

```
$scope.displaySum = function(){
   //code to get result from getSum
   var sum = $scope.getSum();
   //do something with sum here
};
```

You *could* assign the value of `getSum()` to a variable in your scope

```
$scope.sum = $scope.getSum();
```

and bind your html to `$scope.sum` instead of `$scope.getSum()`, and then access `$scope.sum` from within `$scope.displaySum`, but then the span with the sum won't automatically update if your weights change.

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0uAOTpTdZyZSj9n92F2?p=preview) to see it working.

Also, if your weights are going to be editable, you'll want to store them as an array of objects instead of just an array of integers.  Otherwise, the bindings in your ng-repeat won't update correctly.

### Update

Generalize your `getSum` function to take a `line` as a parameter.  Then inside your ng-repeat you can call it like this:

```
getSum(line)
```

Similarly, you can call `displaySum` like this:

```
displaySum(lines[0])
```

You actually don't even need `displaySum`.  Just show the sums like this

```
<div>Sum value from line1:{{getSum(lines[0])}}</div>
<div>Sum value from line2:{{getSum(lines[1])}}</div>
<div>Sum value from line3:{{getSum(lines[2])}}</div>
```

Or better yet

```
<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
    Sum value from line{{$index+1}}:{{getSum(line)}}
</div>
```

[New Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8J12ynM6TebjW1VqJMYX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me. In the real app the weight and tara spans is contenteditable divs...

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't recommending you do it that way.  Check out the plunker I added to my answer.  Clicking on the sum outputs 454 to the console.

Comment: Maybe there is something i don't understand, but won't this just rerun the function? Lets say I call the function multiple times in the DOM.. then i want to get the value from one of the runs... New plunker that better explains it on the way....

Comment: Yes, it will rerun the function.  Is that a problem?  Your view is going to rerun the function if any of the weights change, as well, so the results you get when you run it in the controller will be the same as what the view displays.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need jQuery here.

Actually, you have access to `getSum()` everywhere in your controller, e. g.:

```
var test = $scope.getSum();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear (I'm pretty new to this).. I don't want to access the function... I want the value that the function has returned when it was used from the DOM. In the plunker I just want the value 454

Comment: @user3320468 Did you tried to `console.log` this code? `test` actually has value you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, the ng-click="test" was to run console.log, but still can't find the value, just the function

Comment: @user3320468 Are you doing the same? `console.log( $scope.getSum() );`

Comment: Look at my new plunker, i hope that is better to explain what I want